# Reading from the next line in a file c++

Tags: c++, file-io, while-loop

I'm trying to make an inventory system that reads from a list and stores things in parallel vectors. My vectors are set up as public members in a class that I have included in my code. The text file looks like this

```
1111
Dish Washer
20 250.50 550.50
2222
Micro Wave
75 150.00 400.00
3333
Cooking Range 
50 450.00 850.00
4444
Circular Saw
150 45.00 125.00
6236
Tacos
200 5.00 5.50
```

Here is my code

```
 int main()
{
    char choice;
    Inventory Stocksheet(5); // the included list has 5 items if a text file has more then it should scale fine
    int id, ordered;
    string name;
    double manuprice, price;
    ifstream data;
    data.open("Inventory Data.txt");
    if (data.fail())
    {
        cout << "Data sheet failed to open \n";
        exit(1);
    }
    while (data >> id )
    {
        Stocksheet.itemID.push_back(id);
        getline(data,name);
        Stocksheet.itemName.push_back(name); // this is where my code fails
        data >> ordered;
        Stocksheet.pOrdered.push_back(ordered);
        Stocksheet.pInstore.push_back(ordered);
        data >> manuprice;
        Stocksheet.manuPrice.push_back(manuprice);
        data >> price;
        Stocksheet.sellingPrice.push_back(price);
    }

    do
    {
        cout << "     Your friendly neighborhood tool shack\n";
        cout << "Select from the following options to proceed \n";
        cout << "1. Check for item \n";
        cout << "2. Sell an iem \n";
        cout << "3. Print Report \n";
        cout << "Input any number other than 1,2 or 3 to exit \n";
        cout << "Selection : ";
        cin >> choice; // think about sstream here
        switch (choice)
        {
        case '1': checkforitem(Stocksheet);
            break;
        case '2': sellanitem(Stocksheet);
            break;
        case '3': printthereport(Stocksheet);
            break;
        default: cout << " ^-^ Exiting the shop. Have a fantastic day! ^-^ \n";
            break;
        }

    }while ((choice == '1') || (choice == '2') || (choice == '3'));
    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I commented where my code breaks. In the while loop the number id is pushed to my first vector but the name is blank and every value after that is left blank. Is there something wrong with how my loop is set up?

Comment: Not going to post as an answer because it's a bit off of what you're asking: you might want to consider breaking the data up into something like a vector of lines, which would be much easier to process (random access of any line becomes a breeze), especially if you need to do more operations like this in the future.

Comment: @WilliamKappler I have no idea how I would go about doing that. I just learned what a vector was. So far the only thing I new about a vector was my lab instructor saying "No you cannot use a vector or struct you have to use an array"

Comment: A vector is basically an array, but a more friendly one implemented as a class with features like managed resizing and the ability to determine the size later. You figure out how many lines you need to store (should be number of `\n` characters + 1), resize an `std::vector< std::string >` to that size, then read to each `\n` while writing to each consecutive element of the vector, until you hit the end of the input. Essentially, you need a C++ version of PHP's `explode()`. I said this might be aside your question because it starts on an entirely different track of programming such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `>>` operator you get a "word" type thing. It stops on whitespace. So then when you call `getline`, it reads the newline at the end of the first line (with the id on it) and stops. So your `name` is blank.

You can call `data.ignore()` before you switch to `getline` and that will take care of the newline. Be careful mixing the `>>` operator with `getline`. It doesn't do what you'd expect.

Comment: OMFG this worked like a charm! Except I used `data.ignore()`Now my loop iterates through the 5 items and pushes them to their proper places and I can continue debugging this program. Thank you sooo much!  Oh and I had to work in `getline()` with the file I'm given some of the names are seperated by white space so I need to grab the entire thing

Comment: @Hikari Sorry, yeah, `data.ignore()`. I forgot you were working with a file and not `cin`. I'll edit the answer so it's clear later. I don't blame you for using `getline`, it's necessary, but it's just a quirk that's annoying. To be less annoying and more consistent you could try `scanf` instead of mixing.

Comment: It's not really a "quirk" when it's doing the only sensible thing a computer could do in the general case. What you should _really_ do is read the lines _all_ by `getline` and parse/convert them individually as needed.